# Google script, issue with using setValues due to an undefined array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script to check for new data from one spreadsheet to another and I've created an array that is giving me an error when compiling. The error is 
TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 29, file "Code") 
Line 29 is the last line, ".setValues(arr);" 
I've looked at several examples of using setValues and can't see my error.

Thanks in advance.

```
var arr = [];
var rangeval = range.getValues()
    .forEach(function (r, i, v) {
        if (r[1] == 'Amber') arr.push([v[i][0], v[i][3], v[i][2]]);
    });
var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1UXPyPmOcsLzyBXAzKax8oVVvUSRC8bfgLP2S7j2F9Yw')
    .getSheetByName('Sheet1');
destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length)
    .setValues(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that arr[0] is undefined at execution time.

Since getValues() returns a two dimensional array, it looks to me like  `if (r[1] == 'Amber')`  will always evaluate to False.

You probably want `(r[i][1] == 'Amber')`

Generally when using setvalues this way I do a check first:

```
if(arr.length > 0)
  destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
```

To troubleshoot further, you can use the built in debugger to step through execution, or use Logger.log() calls and check the logs under via Logs under the View menu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I had just reached the conclusion that the array was null as well. I did make the change you suggested but the error persists.

Comment: @MS If you need to make clarifications about your question, please edit it.

Comment: @MS I just figured out that you already posted a follow up question - > https://stackoverflow.com/q/48217067/1595451